# Why are arrays sometimes linked?

Tags: .net, vb.net

Something like this works as expected:

```
        Dim test(1) As Integer
        test = {1, 2}
        Dim test2(1) As Integer
        test2 = test
        test = {3, 4}
        test2 = {4, 5}
```

But sometimes after setting one array to be equal to another, the changes to one will affect the other. This forces me to add `.clone` everywhere. Why is this?

Comment: array variables basically hold memory addresses that point at the data, when you set test2 = test you're copying the address pointing to the data, not the data itself. you have to redim a new array from the first one.

Comment: Array variable is just pointer to array data, When you assign an array variable by another array variable, the two variable now point to same data, Change to either will affect both array

Comment: An array is a reference type. The variable only points to the data in memory. You can read about reference types and value types on [**the MSDN**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code `test2 = test` makes the two variables `test2` and `test` point to the same array. If you made any changes to the array like:

```
test2(1) = 0
test(0) = 99
```

Then both those changes would be visible via both `test` and `test2`, because *they are the same array*.

However, when you do:

```
test = {3, 4}
```

You are not altering the existing array; you are creating a new one and making `test` point to it. It works the same way as `test2 = test` - you're redirecting the variable to point to a different array in memory.

So then you're back to having two separate arrays, and changes in one are not reflected in the other.

Answer (score 0):

`test2 = test` This means that those object references refer to the same object. So if you change `test` then it will also change `test2`.